# Render partial in devise when user is signed in and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to render a partial only when someone is logged in and the current user in devise.  It may be redundant to check if user signed in if we're checking if current_user is the page viewing.

For example: I am logged in as User 1. I want to show a message when I go to /users/1 but not show it when I go to /users/2.

The same goes for reverse: User 2 should be able to go to /users/1 and not see the message, but would on /users/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the devise method `current_user`. In your controller, set a variable that you can check in your view that says what user this user page belongs to. Then just check whether it's the same as the `current_user`.

For instance, in your User controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Then in your view:

```
if (user_signed_in? && current_user == @user)
   ... render your partial
```